# How to answer this car question?

Tags: interrogatives

> What do cars run on ?

Is the answer gas or road?

I am confused by this question.

Comment: Where you said "gar" (a kind of fish), did you mean "gas"?

Comment: @ThePhoton **gas**

Comment: It sounds like a joke or riddle, punning on the two senses.

Comment: Please add some context for this question. All of us know that cars need fuel and that cars go on roads. If this is a real question and not a joke or riddle, in what context did it arise and why is it important? That may help us write a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cars drive (or we drive them) on the road.

They run on gas.

In this usage, "run on" means "to be powered by" rather than "move on top of".